# How do i delete a file that is installed from post installation of a rpm and is not needed in the upgrade of it?

Tags: rpm, specifications, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Following is the first version of rpm spec

```
    %post
    if [ "$1" = "1" ];
    then
        touch /usr/bin/item1.txt
        touch /usr/bin/item2.txt
        echo "i am in and this line is written from rpm 1-1">>/usr/bin/item1.txt
        echo "i am in and this line is written from rpm 1-1">>/usr/bin/item2.txt
    fi          
    %preun    
    if [ "$1" = "0" ];
    then
        sed -i "/i am in and this line is written from rpm 1-1 /d" /usr/bin/item1.txt
        sed -i "/i am in and this line is written from rpm 1-1 /d" /usr/bin/item2.txt
        rm -rf /usr/bin/item1.txt
        rm -rf /usr/bin/item2.txt
    fi
    if [ "$1" = "1" ];
    then
     # what should be here ?
    fi
```

The seacond version of rpm spec is as follows

```
%post
if [ "$1" = "1" ];
then
    touch /usr/bin/item1.txt
    echo "xyz1" >> /usr/bin/item1.txt
    touch /usr/bin/item3.txt
    echo "xyz3" >> /usr/bin/item3.txt
fi

if [ "$1" = "2" ];
then
    # what should be here if i want to remove item2.txt file and add item3.txt
fi
%preun
if [ "$1" = "0" ];
then
# will i have to remove all the files item1 and item 2 along with item3.txt here 
fi

if [ "$1" = "1" ];
then
    ##
fi
```

i want to simply remove the file item2 which is already intalled in post install script of base rpm and install item3.txt file as part of upgrade.

Comment: the last part of your question is not very clear. What do you want to do exactly in your preun or postun scripts?

Comment: @ChrisMaes i am trying to write some custom specs and trying to upgrade them and i was wondering what would the preun and postun scripts whcih execute during upgrades contain

Comment: well the sections only need to contain something if you want something particular to happen upon update (run some script, add user, remove user, ...)

Comment: a good reference about the sections and the order in which they are executed and with what parameters: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets?rd=Packaging:ScriptletSnippets

Comment: @ChrisMaes i tried to create a scenario that depicts my doubt hope you can understand :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a wrong idea of how rpm packaging works. Hereis a sample workflow that would create `package-1.0.0-0.spec` and `package-2.0.0-0.rpm`file:

create the two files that you want to package (these command happen outside the spec file, just like when you write code):

```
echo "i am in and this line is written from rpm 1" > item1.txt
echo "i am in and this line is written from rpm 1" > item2.txt
```

now create a spec file just beside with these parts:

```
Version: 1.0.0
Release: 0

%install
install -d -m 0755 "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/usr/bin/"
cp item1.txt ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/usr/bin/
cp item2.txt ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/usr/bin/

%files
/usr/bin/item1.txt
/usr/bin/item2.txt
```

this will create `package-1.0.0-0.rpm` containing item1.txt and item2.txt
now suppose we want to create the next version; then:

```
echo "xyz1" >> item1.txt
echo "xyz3" >> item3.txt
```

the spec file should now contain:

```
Version: 2.0.0
Release: 0

%install
install -d -m 0755 "${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/usr/bin/"
cp item1.txt ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/usr/bin/
cp item3.txt ${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}/usr/bin/

%files
/usr/bin/item1.txt
/usr/bin/item3.txt
```

which will create `package-2.0.0-0.rpm`. Upon upgrade, `rpm` will now remove /usr/bin/item2.txt and install the new versions of item1.txt and item3.txt

Comment: thanks for the answer @Chris Maes I understand that's the ideal way to do things but this is the scenario i am facing with the already written codes

Comment: I'm sorry, your way of working is very complex and will never work on the long run. Your best shot is to adapt your way of working to how `rpm`was intended to be used. I can't do anything else for you.

Comment: If you think my answer solved your problem, consider accepting it (checkmark next to my answer); this will show others that your problem is solved.